# batch process tasklist check not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, windows-server-2008, batch-processing

I posted this before but at the time it seemed like it was working but I see now that it is not.

I am trying to check if certain processes are running and if not it should start a new instance of that process. The process is a .NET program that must be run.

```
@echo off 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq GEIndexParser.exe" | find /I "GEIndexParser.exe">
nul &&(
echo PROCESS GEIndexParser.exe IS ALREADY RUNNING!
)||(
echo GEIndexParser.exe IS NOT RUNNING! STARTING THE NEW PROCESS!
cmd /c start "ETPARSER" "C:\Users\me\Documents\
Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Projects2013\
GEIndexParser\bin\Debug\GEIndexParser.exe"
)
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

By the way I am trying to run it on a windows server 2008 machine and it does run when I set up the job in scheduled tasks but does not see an existing process running and still executes it. This results in tons of instances of the process running.

Thanks to comment suggestion about the syntax I changed it a bit

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq GEIndexParser.exe" | find /I "GEIndexParser.exe">nul &&(
echo PROCESS GEIndexParser.exe IS ALREADY RUNNING!)
pause
||
(
echo GEIndexParser.exe IS NOT RUNNING! STARTING THE NEW PROCESS!
cmd /c start "ETPARSER" "C:\Users\me\Documents\
Visual Studio2010\Projects\Projects2013\GEIndexParser\bin\Debug\GEIndexParser.exe"
)
```

seems to be working now.

Comment: Please remove end of line after tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq GEIndexParser.exe" | find /I "GEIndexParser.exe">     and tell if it works.

Comment: I am not sure if that was it exactly since I added the endofline when making the post but deleted any additional spaces and seems to be fine now. Thanks

Comment: WANT TO ADD this as well; useful for me; changing the command line window title ---> TITLE new title

Answer (score 0):

So the final code would be:

```
@echo off 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq GEIndexParser.exe" | find /I "GEIndexParser.exe">nul &&(
   echo PROCESS GEIndexParser.exe IS ALREADY RUNNING!
)||(
   echo GEIndexParser.exe IS NOT RUNNING! STARTING THE NEW PROCESS!
   cmd /c start "ETPARSER" "C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio2010\Projects\Projects2013\GEIndexParser\bin\Debug\GEIndexParser.exe"
)
```